# Change HTML with iMacros

Tags: javascript, html, imacros

I am trying to change this with *iMacros*:

```
<div id="outerd3">    
  <img src="bnner0.jgp" alt="">    
  <img src="flamingo.jpg" alt="">    
  <img src="avatar.jpg" alt="">   
</div>
```

into this

```
<div id="outerd3">    
  <img src="avatar.jpg" alt="">    
  <img src="avatar.jpg" alt="">    
  <img src="avatar.jpg" alt="">    
</div>
```

If possible, please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While we are happy to help, it is expected for you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a specific problem you are facing in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you've already tried, and what effect that had.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for change img src.

```
$('img').each(function () {
    $(this).attr("src","avatar.jpg");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is a solution for 'iMacros':

```
URL GOTO=javascript:(function(){var<SP>img=document.querySelector("#outerd3").querySelectorAll("img");for(i=0;i<img.length;i++)img[i].src="avatar.jpg";})();
```